# Package complete application as a single jQuery UI page

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like to port a thick client application to jQuery UI. The current application connects to a JSON service to fetch data. This data is then maintained within the client and is shared among several screens.

Is it possible to do something equivalent using jQuery UI (or other JavaScript RIA frameworks)? Specifically, can the entire app be downloaded as a single HTML page which can then act as a standalone application in the browser. The application should be able to navigate from one screen to another without loosing state. For example, after successfully logging in from the login screen, the UI should switch to a "logged-in" screen with six tabs. Every tab should be able to access the username that were entered in the login screen.

Is this possible? Is it an acceptable practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research I found that this is indeed an acceptable practice. The term used for it is "Single Page Application". Here are some links that point to a bunch of resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810086/recommended-javascript-framework-for-single-page-applications
- [Architecture of a single-page JavaScript web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050869/architecture-of-a-single-page-javascript-web-application)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application
- http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/